# preventing users to get password from mysql or script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, passwords

I have a link on my page which will open another website by means of a  `return window.open(` 
. this website is an shop which provided me to buy and eventually get an xml for the others.
If i log in to the site i go to `www.thewebsiteoftheshop.com/basket?username=user1&password=test`

then the user can see the password in the url,

the first problem is:
I have a database where is store the username and password which i will later put with variables in the url for username and password.
I know have inserted the username and password, with the password as Md5.
put if i know select these data from the database it will give me the hashed password and then the link won't work.

but the second problem is:
I don't want the user to see or retrieve the password

I thought of, just putting this page(where the link is) on a secure page with login. But the only problem is that if i put the password not hashed but as a normal string in my database, that maybe someone from outside can get the password. So this will be risky.

Comment: As long as the shop doesn't provide a save way to login e.g. at least hashed password, or better a commonly used login system as oauth or similiar. you don't have a chance to hide the password. Event if parameters can be provided by POST a user can read the password.

Maybe you should look for a safer shop

Comment: Maybe you could look into CURL and execute the request on server side only. but if you have to show the shop to the user this won't be possible

Comment: The problem is not on your side, and cannot be solved on your side solely. It takes both your side and the shop to secure the authentication mechanism. As a one way example, your side need to hash or encrypt the password, the other hand (the shop) need to be able to understand the hash or encryption in order to authenticate.